# Need an explanation on how a function expression is being passed as an argument in a function declaration

Tags: javascript

Passing a function expression as an argument

Example:

```
var greeting = function(first,last) {
return "Hello " + first + last;
};
function greet(frst,lst,word) {
var result = word(frst,lst);
console.log(result);
}
greet("Joe","Bob",greeting);
```

I understand that `var greeting` is being assigned the anonymous function and this function is being passed as an expression.

I understand that in the global execution context, that variable greeting is set aside some memory space, but not the function inside of it.

I know that function greet , is set aside memory space and when we invoke the function greet, it creates memory space for the local variable result. Now the variable result is assigned to `word(frst,lst)` does this make it a function? meaning is `word(frst,lst)` a function expression?

What I do not understand is...

How is it that when we invoke the function with:

`greet("Joe","Bob",greeting);`

that the browser is able to take the argument "Joe" and "Bob" and place them into `word(frst,lst)` and then use the parameter greeting which is a variable that runs a function to add it's two parameters, when the parameters from the variable and the function greet have different names? I do not understand how the arguments are being passed into that to give us the result of `"Hello Joebob"`.

Please correct me if I am wrong in any of my statements and I do appreciate all your help.

Please help!!

thank you!

Comment: All of them are simply references to a function object that is stored somewhere in memory. So `word` is a copy of a reference that points to the same function in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's take it one by one.

**1. Functions as first class objects in JS**

In JS, functions are treated as first class objects that means you can store, pass it as arguments, receive in function parameters in the same way you do with other objects or variables.

In your case, the anonymous function is assigned to variable `greeting`. This function/function reference can be passed to any other function as normal variables.

When you pass any function to another function, it is passed by reference and in order to execute this you have to invoke it with pair of parenthesis `greeting(..)`.

**2. Passing of arguments in function references**

JS functions do not perform type checking or number of arguments passed to a function when they are invoked. The passed parameters maintained the same order when they are received as arguments in the function definitions. 
such as - 
`function dummy(x, y, x){}` if invoked as `dummy(1,2,3)` will receive `x` as `1`, `y` as `2` and so on. If some of the parameters are not passed such as `dummy(1, 3)`, the respective argument will be set as `undefined` by JS itself. These are done implicitly by JS engine.

**JS function `arguments` object**

JavaScript functions have a built-in object called the arguments object.
The argument object contains an array of the arguments used when the function was called (invoked). With every function invocation, this object is set with the passed parameters  and can be retrieved within the function. For eg.

```
x = findMax(1, 123, 500, 115, 44, 88);

  function findMax() {
    var i;
    var max = -Infinity;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     if (arguments[i] > max) {
        max = arguments[i];
     }
  }
 return max;
}
```

In the above example, since arguments to the `findMax` are dyanmic ie. we are not sure with how many numbers it will get invoked, it is better to retrieve the arguments from the `arguments` object instead of as direct function parameters.

Good read - 
http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function
http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.arguments

Answer (score 1):

Let's run through the evaluation process together:

```
// Def 1
var greeting = function(first, last) {
  return "Hello " + first + last;
};

// Def 2
function greet(frst, lst, word) {
  var result = word(frst, lst);
  console.log(result);
}

// Call
greet("Joe", "Bob", greeting);
```

When the execution reaches (Def 1), the right hand side, which is a function expression, is evaluated in the global context to produce a closure, a data structure that contains a pointer to a compiled function and a pointer to the global context (since that's where this function is being defined). The result of this evaluation is associated with the identifier `greeting` in this toplevel.

Next the execution reaches (Def 2), where similarly, a closure is created and the result stored in `greet`.

Interesting things begin at (Call). To evaluate `greet("Joe", "Bob", greeting)`, the compiler adds a new stack frame/activation record on top of the topmost one that's used at the top level with slots for `greet`'s three formal parameters (namely `frst`, `lst`, and `word`) and its one local variable (namely `result`). Then, `"Joe"`, `"Bob"`, and `greeting` are all evaluated and their values are assigned to those slots. `"Joe"` and `"Bob"` evaluate to some string representations of those names, and `greeting` we know from Def 1 evaluates to a closure.  Then in that stack frame the evaluation of `greet`, which from Def 2 we know is a closure, begins.

- First, `word`, which is now assigned the value of the closure named by `greeting`, is going to be applied to the values of `frst` and `lst`, which, in this stack frame the compiler has assigned the strings `"Joe"` and `"Bob"`.

  - To evaluate the value of `greeting`, the compiler creates the third stack frame with two slots for its 2 formal parameters `first` and `last`, assigns `"Joe"` and `"Bob"` to those respectively, and begins executing the body of `greeting`. The body of `greeting` concatenates "Joe" and "Bob" and prepends them with "Hello", returning the string "Hello JoeBob".
- Next, that result is stored in the slot called `result`.
- Next, a new stack frame is going to be allocated to make the call to the build-in function `console.log` (the story is very similar to the other calls, so I won't go into the details).
- Lastly, `greet` returns `undefined` to its call site, which doesn't do anything with that value. The program then finishes executing.

Answer (score 1):

If you would analyse this step by step (dry run this) , then this is what happens when you call `greet("Joe","Bob",greeting);`

**STEP-1**

```
first| lst | word
================================================
Joe  | Bob  | function(first,last) {
     |      |     return "Hello " + first + last;
     |      |  };
```

**STEP-2**

```
var result = word(frst,lst);
```

what happens here, is the function that the varible word is refering to in step-1 gets called with the value of the first and lst variable.

```
ie. word('Joe', 'Bob');
```

so dry running this function we get

```
var greeting = function(first,last) {
   return "Hello " + first + last;
};

first | last | return value = ("Hello " + first + last) | result
================================================================
Joe   | Bob  |  Hello JoeBob                            | Hello JoeBob
```

So, `console.log(result);` = `Hello JoeBob`